# ptpd won't start as a service

Tags: ubuntu, timestamps

Now this really is getting me nuts. I installed `ptpd` on ubuntu 14.04 and it I just can't get this to work to run as a service.
In `/etc/default/ptpd` I have the following entries:
`START_DAEMON = yes` and 
`PTPD_OPTS = "-G -h -b eth0"` but that won't work.

When I do `sudo ptpd -G -h -b eth0` by command line then the program is starting fine.

I already tried to put `ptpd -G -h -b eth0` into a batch file called `usr/local/bin/start.sh` and start this file by `/etc/rc.local` but that won't work too. The program is just not starting automatically.
Any kind of help is very appreciated.

Comment: What does a check of the service status tell you?

Comment: The service itself is listed as `ptpd` when I execute a `service --status-all` but it says that it's not running.

Comment: How about "service ptpd status"?

Comment: It says `ptpd is not running`.
Edit: No firewall or antivirus is running on my system.

Comment: It doesn't give you any further messages?

Comment: No way. Nothing.

Comment: Are there maybe other ways I can try to start the command on startup than rc.local?

Comment: OMG, I am such an idiot. The problem that the service itself is not running by the entries in `/etc/default/ptpd` still exists, but my workaround with the batchfile was not working because the batchfile `start.sh` was not executable. Now it runs. Thank you anyway, Raman Sailopal!

Answer (score 0):

I also had some trouble running it, but unrelated to the valid solution found.

This could help more people:
`sudo ptpd -G -h -b eth0` --> `-h` shows the help. Of course it won't run... Probably the output is hidden. Try to see something with `sudo journalctl -xeu ptpd` or try to add `-D|--debug` and/or `-V|--verbose`

Furthermore, enable the service you'll also need:
`sudo systemctl enable ptpd`. Otherwise it won't start.